# RHEL 8 IPA/DNS secondary to Windows AD/DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, rhel8

I have a particular scenario that I am trying to implement at work.  I work on an enterprise that has both Windows and Linux clients and would like the added Linux benefits of utilizing an IPA server for the Linux clients, but since I also have Windows clients I need Active Directory too. Here is where I am stumped…

I need the Windows DC to also serve as a primary DNS server for the entire domain and would like the RHEL IPA server to serve as the backup DNS server in case the primary ever goes down.

I realize that I can configure a trust between the Windows DC and the RHEL IPA and that the RHEL IPA server can have integrated DNS (I have configured this and gotten the trust established), but the problem is the IPA server won’t answer any DNS queries whatsoever - it only forwards to the Windows DNS server.

I have confirmed this using tcpdump and the fact that every time I try to query for something from any client on the domain the IPA server ends with a “fail” or “error” response. With that,

I have also tried installing bind9 on the RHEL server first and then tried installing IPA without integrated DNS (and vice versa) but couldn’t get that to work right either.

Any help/advice is much appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: AD can be a primary to an secondary using zone transfer. You should elaborate on the symptoms, as "couldn’t get that to work" isn't useful.

Comment: I came across this link, might be helpful , I second what Greg says https://vswitchzero.com/2021/02/24/linux-and-bind9-as-a-dns-secondary-for-active-directory/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.